# Run Gulp with shortcut on Windows from the start menu

Tags: cmd, gulp, shortcut

I'm using [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/). Let's say I have it installed on this location on my own computer:

```
/wamp/www/sites/my-site/gulpfile.js
```

Then I start CMD and use CD to get to the path and then I write `Gulp` to get it started.

Is it possible to do all that from a startmenu click (shortcut)? Like, I click on an icon in the start menu that says "My site" and then it goes to the correct path and run Gulp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to install gulp as a global dependency. For that you have to run

```
npm install -g gulp
```

Now create a shortcut and change its properties as follows -

1. Edit the target as the path to cmd.exe
2. Write '/k' along with the command you want to run, in your case its 'gulp'
3. Write the path of your project in 'Start in'

Refer this screenshot.

[image]